# How do I correctly use Microsoft flow conditionals with a YES/NO Columnin A sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, office365, power-automate

I have a Sharepoint list that I have created for testing purposes only. What I am testing is sending an email with different content based on a conditional in a Microsoft-flow process. The conditional looks at a Yes/ No column called *Test_YES_NO_DEFAULT_YES*. As the name implies, that column always sends back a YES. The process works fine, but the conditional always sends back the *IF NO* in the email. This is what the flow looks like!
[image]**I have had tried 1, True, TRUE, true, yes, Yes, and YES with no results.**
What do I have to do In order for the conditional to execute the *IF YES*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "Edit in advanced mode", and enter this in the text field:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['Test_YES_NO_DEFDAULT_YES'], true)
```

Please double check the name of the column (I took the one from your screenshot).

EDIT:
Note that this is not the same as you tried (true), since writing "true" in Basic mode puts the string in the formula, instead of the bool value `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint designer workflow for checking the condition.Once item is created trigger the workflow to check for your condition. Content of mail you can store in SharePoint list. SharePoint designer workflow have many options for checking the condition for the workflow.

Sanjeev

Comment: for whatever reason, I cannot get SharePoint designer to work with the office 365 version of SharePoint. If I could, I would much rather go with SharePoint designer. I do not like Microsoft flow at all and I think it is just going to confuse allot of people.

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is a boolean, you need to convert your 'true' to a boolean via the bool() function.

Using your example, this should work for you: 
@equals(triggerBody()?['Test_YES_NO_DEFAULT_YES'], bool(1))

MS Flow is built on top of Logic Apps, so for more info, check out the functions section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language